# Display member discounted prices to non-members in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, woocommerce-memberships

In WooCommerce, I have 3 membership tiers (silver, gold and platinum) and I applied higher discount rate for higher membership tier.

I would like show the 4 different prices (non-member, silver, gold and platinum) to everyone such that they know how much they can save on each product if they join the membership. For example:

- Regular Price: $100
- Silver Member: $90
- Gold Member: $80
- Platinum Member: $70

I tried [the code below](https://wpquestions.com/Display_member_pricing_to_a_non_member_in_woocommerce_memberships/27590):

```
function bsc_wc_memberships_members_only_product_price() {
    global $product;

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( !wc_memberships_is_user_active_member($user->ID, 'test') ) {

        $id = $product->get_id();
        $discount = get_post_meta( $id, 'member_price', true );
        $price = $product->get_price();

        echo 'Member price: $'.$total = $price - $discount;
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'bsc_wc_memberships_members_only_product_price' );
```

But it doesn't really work unfortunately... Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an obvious mistake in:

```
echo 'Member price: $'.$total = $price - $discount;
```

that should be instead just:

```
echo 'Member price: $'. $price - $discount;
```

or even better:

```
echo 'Member price: '. wc_price( $price - $discount );
```

But as this are displayed prices you need to use something a bit different and more complete like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'bsc_wc_memberships_members_only_product_price' );
function bsc_wc_memberships_members_only_product_price() {
    global $product;

    if ( ! wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( get_current_user_id(), 'test' ) ) {

        $discount     = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array('price' => $product->get_meta('member_price') ) );
        $price        = wc_get_price_to_display( $product );

        $silver_price = $price - $discount;

        echo '<span class="silver-price">' . __('Member price') . ': ' . wc_price( $silver_price ) . '</span>';
    }
}
```

Checking that a custom field meta value really exist on `member_price` meta key for this product under `wp_postmeta` database table.

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should better work.